# my auth controller for login is error , cannot get the data from server side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios, jwt

Hi guys i am newbie in react js, i have a problem about getting data from server side and routing in reactjs, i am using axios and jsonwebtoken to get the data, but it's not working,

i have check the inspect from browser and there's no error in there, but my website is still not responding

maybe you can help me to fix this problem

thanks in advance

Here is my code from "AuthController.js"

```
import UserModel from "../Models/userModel.js";
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";


// Registering a new User
export const registerUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password, firstname, lastname } = req.body
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
  const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)
  // req.body.passowrd = hashedPass

  const newUser = new UserModel({
    username,
    password: hashedPass,
    firstname,
    lastname
  })

  try {
    // check username
    const oldUser = await UserModel.findOne({ username })
    if (oldUser) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "The username is already exist" })
    }

    const user = await newUser.save()
    const token = jwt.sign({
      username: user.username, id: user._id
    }, process.env.JWT_KEY, { expiresIn: '1h' })

    res.status(200).json({ user, token })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
  }
};


// login user 

export const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ username: username })

    if (user) {
      const validity = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

      validity ? res.status(200).json(user) : res.status(400).json("Wrong Password")
      const token = jwt.sign(
        { username: user.username, id: user._id },
        process.env.JWTKEY,
        { expiresIn: "1h" }
      );
      res.status(200).json({ user, token });
    } else {
      res.status(404).json("User not found");
    }

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
  }
}
```

here is my Auth Reducer

```
const authReducer = (state = { auhtData: null, loading: false, error: false }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "AUTH_START": return { ...state, loading: true, error: false };
    case "AUTH_SUCCES":
      localStorage.setItem("profile", JSON.stringify({ ...action?.data }))
      return { ...state, authData: action.data, loading: false, error: false };
    case "AUTH_FAIL": return { ...state, loading: false, error: true }
    default: return state;
  }
}

export default authReducer
```

my Auth action

```
import * as AuthApi from '../api/AuthRequests.js';

export const logIn = (formData) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: "AUTH_START" });
  try {
    const { data } = await AuthApi.logIn(formData);
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH_SUCCESS", data: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH_FAIL" });
  }
};

export const signUp = (formData) => async (dispatch) => {

  dispatch({ type: "AUTH_START" })
  try {
    const { data } = await AuthApi.signUp(formData)
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH_SUCCES", data: data })

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH_FAIL" })
  }
}
```

my Auth Request for API

```
import axios from 'axios'


const API = axios.create({ baseURL: "http://localhost:5000" });

export const logIn = (formData) => API.post('/auth/login', formData);

export const signUp = (formData) => API.post('/auth/register', formData);
```

here is my index.js

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors'
import AuthRoute from './Routes/AuthRoute.js'
import UserRoute from './Routes/UserRoute.js'
import PostRoute from './Routes/PostRoute.js'


//Routes
const app = express();


// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit: '30mb', extended: true,
}))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: '30mb', extended: true,
}))

app.use(cors())

dotenv.config();


mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`Listening to ${process.env.PORT}`)))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));


// usage of routes
app.use('/auth', AuthRoute)
app.use('/user', UserRoute)
app.use('/post', PostRoute)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var passport  = require("passport");
var passportJWT = require('passport-jwt');
var User = require("../models/user");
var config = require('../config');
var ExtractJwt = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;
var Strategy = passportJWT.Strategy;

var opts = {
    secretOrKey: config.secret,
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()
}

module.exports = function () {

    var strategy = new Strategy(opts, function(payload, done) {
        User.findById(payload.id, function(err, user) {
            if (user) {
                return done(null, {id: user.id, payload: user});
            }else {
                return done(new Error("User not found"), null);
            }
        });
    });

    passport.use(strategy);
    return {
        initialize: function() {
            return passport.initialize();

        },
        authenticate: function () {
            const a = passport.authenticate("jwt", {session: false});
            return a;
        }
    };
};
```

You can use  Passport and  middleware.
Also it seems your `process.env.JWTKEY` is missing.
So please check the value via `console.log(process.env.JWTKEY)`